# How to find the derivative of the hidden state of recurrent neural networks?

Tags: backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network, derivation

Recently I am reading the following paper ([link](https://faculty.ucmerced.edu/mhyang/papers/eccv16_rnn_filter.pdf))

```
Liu, Sifei, Jinshan Pan, and Ming-Hsuan Yang. “Learning Recursive Filters for Low-Level Vision via a Hybrid Neural Network.” In Computer Vision – ECCV 2016, edited by Bastian Leibe, Jiri Matas, Nicu Sebe, and Max Welling, 9908:560–76. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Cham: Springer International Publishing, 2016. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-46493-0_34.
```

In the paper, the hidden state of the recurrent neural network, after some simplifications, is modeled as (relation (9) in the paper)

```
h[k] = (1-p) \cdot x[k] + p \cdot h[k - 1].
```

where, `p`, and `x` are `n \tmes 1` vector. Then, it is stated that the derivations with respect to h[k], denoted as \theta [k] is (relation (10) in the paper)

```
\theta[k] = \delta[k] + p \cdot \theta [k + 1]
```

My question: How has this derivation been computed?